# How to iterate through the registers in my vimscript?

Tags: vim

I need to get all the registers that do not have empty strings into a list.

First of all do they exist in a list somewhere already?

Secondly if they do not is there an easier way to get them into a list rather than manually going through them all and checking to see if they are empty?

Maybe I could create a list of the defined registers and use getreg() over that list but I guess I was hoping that the list already existed so I didn't have to create it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to go ...

Comment: I want to make registers easier to use so that I will start using them more. I want to be able autocomplete registers. I know how I want to do everything else I just didn't see an easy way to get at all the registers easily.

Comment: Okey, well (from what I know) there are no such direct solutions (xcept the ones mentioned below). However, for the "normal" purposes of yanking /pasting there are plugins such as yankring and alike, which have a "yankring window" which shows the content of registers. A bit hard to explain so you best check it out for yourself. For autocomplete, I didn't get that quite, so if you could put a word more about what you want to do ... maybe somebody already did something alike.

Comment: It's 4 am in my part of the world - pardon the non cohherent english :/

Comment: ldigas: I figured it all out. I provided the solution below to show what I was trying to do. I was having a little bit of trouble getting the substitute() function to do what I wanted but that was just bonus points anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Well, glad to see you figured it out ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
" Description:
"   Get a list of all the non-empty register indexes
" Example Usage:
"   :call GetNonEmptyRegsIndex( 'print' )    """ To print the registers
"   for n in GetNonEmptyRegsIndex() | echo nr2char(n)." = ".getreg(nr2char(n)) | endfor
" Resources:
"   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-3/index.html
"   irs channel #vim <jamessan>
function! GetNonEmptyRegsIndex( ... )
  " Create the list of register 'indexes' where the the elements are in char2nr form
  let regnum =  range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z'))
  let regnum += range(char2nr('0'), char2nr('9'))
  let regstr =  ['"','-','*','%','/','.','#',':']
  let regnum += map(regstr, 'char2nr(v:val)')

  " Remove the registers that are empty
  "let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) != ""' )
  let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) !~ "^$"' )

  " Remove the registers that are just spaces
  let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) !~ "^\s\+$"' )

  " Remove the registers that have no alpha-num
  "let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) !~ "^\W\+$"' )
  return regnum
endfunction
```

Having to convert from string to num and back again makes the code a little ugly but it works.

This is the full working solution with  to autocomplete the register info. I might tweak it more later but it gives me the basics that I wanted.

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=AutoCompleteRegs()<CR>

function! AutoCompleteRegs()
  call complete( col('.'), GetNonEmptyRegs() )
  return ''
endfunction

" Description:
"   Get a list of all the non-empty registers.
function! GetNonEmptyRegs()
  " Create the list of register 'indexes' where the the elements are in char2nr form
  let regIndexNum = GetNonEmptyRegsIndex()

  " Convert the list of indexes to values
  let regs = map(regIndexNum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val))')
  "let regs = map(regs, 'substitute(v:val,  "^(.*)", "\\U\\1", "g")')
  "let regs = map(regs, "echo substitute(v:val,  '^(.*)', '\U\1', 'g')")
  return regs
endfunction

" Description:
"   Get a list of all the non-empty register indexes
" Example Usage:
"   :call GetNonEmptyRegsIndex( 'print' )    """ To print the registers
"   for n in GetNonEmptyRegsIndex() | echo nr2char(n)." = ".getreg(nr2char(n)) | endfor
" Resources:
"   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-3/index.html
"   irs channel #vim <jamessan>
function! GetNonEmptyRegsIndex( ... )
  " Create the list of register 'indexes' where the the elements are in char2nr form
  let regnum =  range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z'))
  let regnum += range(char2nr('0'), char2nr('9'))
  let regstr =  ['"','-','*','%','/','.','#',':']
  let regnum += map(regstr, 'char2nr(v:val)')

  " Remove the registers that are empty
  "let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) != ""' )
  let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) !~ "^$"' )

  " Remove the registers that are just spaces
  let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) !~ "^\s\+$"' )

  " Remove the registers that have no alpha-num
  "let regnum = filter( regnum, 'getreg(nr2char(v:val)) !~ "^\W\+$"' )
  return regnum
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such list, at least not accessible with vimscript. You can parse the outputs of `:silent reg` (with `silent`: no visible output, but still capturable) captured by `:redir`, but I am not much fond of this command (due to “no nested redirections” and the fact that while target variable will be created at the place where first redir happens, it is populated at the place where second redir happens and referenced by name there, making it possible to append data to any variable or throw errors like `E121: Undefined variable`). I just don’t like such unpredictable commands.